# Generate a unique div for an array of incoming data

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, guid

I have a bunch of data coming in from an external source.

This data comes in the form of an associative array. Keys are a value called `version`, and the data is a JSON object. The version keys can potentially have any character in them.

I want to be able to generate a separate `Div` for each key in the array. I have tried stripping out non alphanumeric characters with the following function

```
var sanitizeVersionName = function(version) {
    var prefixed = 'v' + version;
    return prefixed.replace(/^[^a-z]+|[^\w:.-]+/gi, '');
};
```

And then using the result as an ID for the div. The problem is, if my array contains versions like `"1` and `1`, then the above function returns the same value for both.

Is there any way to assign each one of these version keys in my array a div with a globally unique ID?

Comment: Do you have a sample of your data?

Comment: You may not need to strip out any characters, as long as you are dealing with an html5 document. The only requirements for the id attribute are that it must be unique, contain at least one character and must not have any space characters. https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/datatypes.html#common.data.id

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to strip `[a-z\w]` out of your id. Div id's just need to start with `[a-zA-Z]`, but can have numbers, hyphens and underscores.

If there is a date associated with the data, you could use that:

```
var myDate = new Date('06-03-2014 9:34:03');
prefixed += myDate.getTime();
```

generating new dates one after the other in a loop would not work though, there would be dupes.

You could also use a token generator function, though it's not guaranteed to be globally unique, there's nearly an impossible chance it wouldn't be, with a length of say 16 characters.

```
function makeToken(len) {
    var characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    var string = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var x = Math.round(Math.random() * characters.length);
        string += characters.substr(x, 1);
    }
    return string;
}
```

Comment: Good point made with the DateTime as a unique ID. I've used this technique before, when dynamically adding divs with object to add to a form POST